# Can not join on minecraft Pe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My brother and I are trying to join each other's games in Minecraft Pocket Edition, but we can't.

We have got the same Internet, and can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

●Make sure LAN is enabled in the game settings.

●Make sure you are both connected to the internet, on the same network.

●One of you must be in a world, that world will then appear on the others world list.